# How to make drawer init only once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make the Scaffold's drawer init only once so I make the drawer become an instance variable of the Scaffold:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerDemoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerDemoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const _drawer = _MyDrawer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Drawer')),
      drawer: _drawer,
    );
  }
}

class _MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<_MyDrawer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('call init');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('call build');
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 60),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But `init` still called everytime drawer showed.

How can I make drawer init only once?

Comment: That's to be expected.  The view is being newly created.  If you have any model data that should persist, it needs to be out in model space instead, like a state management solution.